# What does an underscore "_" before a swift variable mean?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the code:

```
var _selected: Bool = false {
    didSet(selected) {
        let animation = CATransition()
        animation.type = kCATransitionFade
        animation.duration = 0.15
        self.label.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "")
        self.label.font = self.selected ? self.highlightedFont : self.font
    }
}
```

Why the variable is "_selected" instead of "selected"?

Comment: I too would like to know what it means, especially in the case of @Binding variables and using them in an init()

Answer (score 10):

It's simply a coding style that shouldn't apply to Swift code.

Developers often mark things with an underscore to indicate that it should be private.

That said, there IS a practical use for the underscore _. Read more about [Local and External Parameter Names for Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_347).

---

So how do you avoid using _selected? Right now you have two variables when you already have the one you need (selected).

Removing the _ will require you to override the member variable (how this should be done).

```
override var selected: Bool {
    didSet {
        println("Hello, \(selected)")
    }
}
```

Additionally, a table view cell will have an overridable method setSelected(selected:animated) that might be worth exploring.

Comment: If the underscore makes no difference, can I remove it? Will it conflict with the "selected" in `didSet(selected)`